# OnClickListener in RecyclerView in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, master-detail

I have master-detail flow created and in Master Fragment, I do have a RecyclerView.
I have problem setting up ClickListener in the RecyclerView.
I am not sure if I am missing something trivial or there is bigger problem, but nearly the same code works perfectly in standard Activity (out of Fragment).

Here's my adapter:

```
//imports
public class StepsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private final StepsAdapterOnClickHandler mClickHandler;
private Recipe recipe;
private List<Step> steps;


//init with Click Handler
public StepsAdapter(StepsAdapterOnClickHandler clickHandler) {
    this.mClickHandler = clickHandler;
}

//set recipe and steps
public void setRecipe(Recipe recipe) {
    this.recipe = recipe;
    this.steps = recipe.steps;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

//get position as ViewType for distinguishing between first View and others
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (steps == null) {
        return 0;
    }

    return steps.size() + 1;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    //setup different layout for first view
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view0 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ingredients_tile, parent, false);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.step_selection_tile, parent, false);


    switch (viewType) {
        case 0:
            return new IngredientsViewHolder(view0);
        default:
            return new ViewHolderX(view);

    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
        case 0:
            IngredientsViewHolder viewHolder0 = (IngredientsViewHolder) holder;

            //set text
            viewHolder0.ingredientsLabelTV.setText("Ingredients");

            break;
        default:

            ViewHolderX viewHolderX = (ViewHolderX) holder;

            viewHolderX.shortDescriptionTV.setText(steps.get(position - 1).shortDescription);

            break;

    }
}


//click interface
public interface StepsAdapterOnClickHandler {
    void onClick(int stepId);
}

//viewHolder for Ingredients
public class IngredientsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView ingredientsLabelTV;

    public IngredientsViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        ingredientsLabelTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ingredients_label_tv);
    }

}

//stepsViewHolder
class ViewHolderX extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView shortDescriptionTV;

    public ViewHolderX(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        shortDescriptionTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.short_description_tv);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mClickHandler.onClick(33);
    }
}
```

And here's my Fragment code:

```
     //imports
public class StepSelectionFragment extends Fragment implements StepsAdapter.StepsAdapterOnClickHandler {

OnStepClickListener mCallback;
RecyclerView stepsListRV;
StepsAdapter mAdapter;
RecipeDatabase mDb;

//mandatory empty builder
public StepSelectionFragment() {
}

//onClic - sends callback to Activity
@Override
public void onClick(int stepId) {
    mCallback.onStepClick(stepId);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    //attach callback to fragment
    try {
        mCallback = (OnStepClickListener) context;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + "must implement Listener");
    }

}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_step_selection, container, false);

    //init db
    mDb = RecipeDatabase.getInstance(getActivity());

    //init recyclerView
    stepsListRV = rootView.findViewById(R.id.step_selection_rv);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    stepsListRV.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    //setup adapter with clickHandler
    mAdapter = new StepsAdapter(this);

    stepsListRV.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    //get recipes from Db
    AppExecutors.getsInstance().getDiskIO().execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Recipe recipe = mDb.recipeDAO().loadRecipe(RecipeViewActivity.getRecipeId());
            mAdapter.setRecipe(recipe);
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

public interface OnStepClickListener {
    void onStepClick(int stepId);
}
```

I think I tried everything.
Whole code can be found at https://github.com/ASheler/BakingApp/tree/AddMasetDetailFlow/app/src/main/java/com/glaserproject/bakingapp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `itemView.setOnClickListener(this);` in adapter ViewHolder

Comment: Holy hell I feel so dumb now. How did I not noticed this the whole day? THANK YOU!!!